# make virtual machine appear a real machine to applications

Tags: virtual-machine

I am using VmWare Workstation 14 and when I install an operating system (any of them) some programs and apps are able to identify that I am using a virtual machine.

I have seen the vm is using virtualized devices that are really named virtual. like for example `VmWare Network Card` or etc. Is there any way to install fake real like hardware drivers on these virtual machines? Can this simple change make the app see this vm as a real machine?

How to make this virtual machine appear as a real machine to applications?
Is there really any way?

Comment: I remember, a long time ago there was some sort of competition where one side tried to make the perfect VM while thr other side tried to make the perfect VM detection. In the end I think the detector won, but with great difficulty and unorthodox methods. I can't remember what the competition was called though...

Comment: @Vilx- I hope there should be a way to make it like a real machine

Comment: I think that it might not be possible in theory, but that you should be able to get pretty close (to the point that it takes a great effort to detect it). However I also suspect that no VM authors would actually bother doing that. There are several drawbacks: First, it's hard to do; second - it's very rarely needed (and arguably is unethical - if the app doesn't want to run in a VM, it probably has a good reason to); and lastly it hurts performance. To get a good performance the modern OS'es are in kahoots with the VM. Undetectability would necessitate the removal of these integrations.

Comment: @Vilx, I applaud your efforts in looking at the ethical dimension of this question. However please consider that the app might be the unethical party. Indeed, the reference I cite in my answer deals with using VMs as hacker honeypots and for isolated study of malware. The authors note that malware will often try to detect whether it's in a VM and alter its behaviour in order to mask its capabilities or purpose.

Comment: @systemPAUSE - True, true. It could go either way.

Answer (score 1):

This was asked as a yes-or-no question so my answer is:

### Yes... probably. But it's a lot of work.

There's a 2006 presentation by Tom Liston and Ed Skoudis that talks about this: https://handlers.sans.org/tliston/ThwartingVMDetection_Liston_Skoudis.pdf

It focuses on VMware, but some of it would also apply to other types of Virtual Machine Environments (VMEs).

In summary, they identify as many things as they can find that would allow VM detection, which would each have to be addressed, and they also mention some VMware-specific mitigations for them.

- **VME artifacts in processes, file system, and/or Windows registry.** These would include the VMtools service and "over 50 different references in the file system to 'VMware' and vmx" and "over 300 references in the Registry to 'VMware'", all of which would have to be deleted or changed.
- **VME artifacts in memory.** Specific regions of memory tend to be different in guests (VMs) than hosts, namely the Interrupt Descriptor Table (IDT), Global
  Descriptor Table (GDT), and Local Descriptor Table (LDT). The method by which the VM is built may allow these to appear the same in guests as they do in hosts.
- **VME-specific virtual hardware.** This would include the drivers you mention like `VmWare Network Card`. The drivers would have to be removed or replaced with drivers that do not match the names or code signatures of any virtual drivers. Probably easiest to do on an open-source system, simply by modifying the driver source code and build.
- **VME-specific processor instructions and capabilities.** Some VMEs add non-standard machine language instructions, or modify the behaviour of existing instructions. These can be changed or removed by editing the VME source code, at the cost of convenient host-guest interaction.
- **VME differences in behaviour.** A VM might respond differently on the network, or fail at time synchonization. This could be mitigated with additional source code changes (on both host and guest) to make the network traffic look closer to normal, and providing sufficient CPU cores to the VM would help make sure it does not run more slowly than wall clock time.

Again this is from 2006, so if anyone has a more up-to-date reference, I'd love to see their answer.